# Data Binding in WPF Data Grid not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

if have the following wpf data grid:

```xml
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding BlocksToGenerateList}"
                  GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  CanUserSortColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding VisibleInGrid, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Typ" Width="150">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=TypeString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Types}"  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ort" Width="150">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Location, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}"  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="False" Width="244"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Control Unit" Binding="{Binding ControllingControlUnit}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsControlUnit}" Width="200"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fehlernummer" Binding="{Binding FaultValue}" IsReadOnly="False" Width="90"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Meldungsnummer" Binding="{Binding MessageValue}" IsReadOnly="False" Width="110"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

All the Bindings are to a class called GridBlock, and BlocksToGenerateList is a ObserverableCollection of Type Item.
Now, every binding works as excpected, except this one: IsReadOnly="{Binding IsControlUnit}".

Can somebody help me, or explain what the issue could be? Thank you!

Edit: Screenshot of binding error in Visual Studio

Error translated to english: Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element

[image]

Edit: Some information about the view model

```cs
        private ObservableCollection<GridBlock> _BlocksToGenerateList;
        public ObservableCollection<GridBlock> BlocksToGenerateList
        {
            get { return _BlocksToGenerateList; }
            set
            {
                if (_BlocksToGenerateList == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _BlocksToGenerateList = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("BlocksToGenerateList");
            }
        }
```

GridBlock has a bool property called IsControlUnit

```cs
        private bool _IsControlUnit;
        public bool IsControlUnit
        {
            get { return _IsControlUnit; }
            set
            {
                if (_IsControlUnit == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _IsControlUnit = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("IsControlUnit");
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you know this binding don't work?

Comment: Even tough the value of the variable "IsControlUnit" ist true, the cell ist still editable. If i set it to false manually (remove binding and hard code false into wpf) i cant edit the cell anymore. All other bindings are working as expected and are displaying the data i want to display

Comment: If the binding fail, you can see the error in the output windows in Visual Studio. Are you sure the variable `IsControlUnit` is true? Maybe you can test by modifying the property code to `public bool IsControlUnit => true;`.

Comment: Perhaps you could post your ViewModel and how it gets instantiated.

Comment: @vernou I am sure its true, i hard coded it to true to test this. There is acutalyy a binding error in visual studio. I will add a screenshot to the question

Comment: @TerryTyson what part of the view model? its a pretty big window i am working on. i will add some important parts

Comment: @Felix We need to see the IsControlUnit property since that is where you are having the problem.

Comment: @TerryTyson There ist nothing special about that. But i put it in the question

Comment: @Felix And you are sure that is not being set to false somewhere? If this whole thing is using the same datacontext, I'm at a loss.

Comment: You german error msg (hallo landsmann) means that the binding doesn't find the governing framwork(content)element with the datacontext it can bind to.
DataContexts are not available for DataGridColumns (only for their celltemplates, that's why DataGridColumn.Binding works).

You would need to put all of this into a DataGridTemplateColumn with a TextBox and bind to the TextBox's IsReadOnly property. Then it will work.

Comment: @TerryTyson yes, i hard coded it to true to test this using
 public bool IsControlUnit => true; 
to test this. still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property ***IsReadOnly*** does not see the **IsControlUnit** field.

You can also use the template for editing and reading.

```xml
<DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>Control Unit</DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ControllingControlUnit}" Width="200" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ControllingControlUnit}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsControlUnit, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

You can also add ***IsEnabled***, then you cannot select text

Answer (score 1):

@lidqy is right.

If i replace the DataGridTextBoxColum with the following DataGridTemplateColumn, it works like a charm. Thank all of you!

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Control Unit" Width="200">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ControllingControlUnit}" IsReadOnly="{Binding 
            IsControlUnit}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```